# opendir dont get content of buffer char * on C language?

Tags: c, arrays, linux, string

Im trying to read files from a given directory using *opendir/readdir* functions from *C* on *Linux*, if the files meet certain parameters like size and type will be copied to certain directory, the directory from where files are read and the destination and the size are read from an *".ini"* file, the problem is when i use *opendir* with i.e *opendir(argv[1])* there is no problem, but if i get the value from *".ini"* file into a char * called i.e *search_path* and pass it to *opendir*
as *opendir(search_path)* the code don't work and i get the message *"No such file or directory"*, here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "minIni.h"


#define sizearray(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))

/*Default values for minIni library function ini_gets*/
#define DEFAULT_FILE_SIZE "100000"
#define DEFAULT_FIREFOX_CACHE "~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/43ty8soo.default-release/cache2/entries/"
#define DEFAULT_CHROMIUM_CACHE "~/.cache/chromium/Default/Cache/"
#define DEFAULT_DEST_DIR "/home/newbee/found/"

/*Utility functions*/
void error(const char *s);
int OSCopyFile(const char *, const char *);
int interesting(char *);
int filesize(char *);
int get_config(char *browser, int *min_filesize, char *cache_dir, char *dest);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
  if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <browser-name>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /*the only argument to the program is the browser in which cache*/
  /*we want the exploration.*/
  char *browser_name = argv[1];

  /*Here i call get_config, that function returns the minimum size for*/
  /*the files (min_file_size), where to search (cache), and where to*/
  /*put the files that met the requirements (dest_dir_conf).*/
  char *cache = malloc(PATH_MAX);
  char *dest_dir_conf = malloc(PATH_MAX);
  int min_file_size;
  int result_config = get_config(
      browser_name, &min_file_size, cache, dest_dir_conf);

  if (result_config != 1)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  DIR *dir;
  struct dirent *ent;
  printf("[DEBUG] %s\n", cache);
  /*And there is the problem, no matters if i pass the 'cache' variable*/
  /*or if i harcoded a string here, opendir failed and error is:*/
      /*No such file or directory*/
  chdir(cache);
  dir = opendir(cache);

  if (dir == NULL)
    error("Error");

  char *dest = NULL;
  int count = 0;

  while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
    if ((strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") != 0) && (strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") != 0)) {
      /*The interesting function determine if the file is of a given type and*/
      /*return 1 if true, and 0 if not.*/
      if ((interesting(ent->d_name))
          && (filesize(ent->d_name) >= min_file_size)) {
        dest = malloc(strlen(dest_dir_conf) + strlen(ent->d_name));
        strcpy(dest, dest_dir_conf);
        strcat(dest, ent->d_name);
        OSCopyFile(ent->d_name, dest);
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  closedir(dir);
  printf("[Job finish, %d files was copied.]\n", count);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/** errors info. **/
void error(const char *s) {
  perror(s);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/** get the file size. **/
int filesize(char *archivo) {
  FILE *fp;
  long fsize;

  fp = fopen(archivo, "r");
  if (fp) {
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return fsize;
  } 
  return -1;
}

/** copy files. **/
int OSCopyFile(const char *source, const char *destination) {
  int input, output;
  if ((input = open(source, O_RDONLY)) == -1)
    return -1;
  if ((output = creat(destination, 0660)) == -1) {
    close(input);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__FreeBSD__)
  int result = fcopyfile(input, output, 0, COPYFILE_ALL);
#else
  off_t bytesCopied = 0;
  struct stat fileinfo = {0};
  fstat(input, &fileinfo);
  int result = sendfile(output, input, &bytesCopied, fileinfo.st_size);
#endif

  close(input);
  close(output);

  return result;
}

/** determine if the file is interesting (for me, at least ;) ). **/
int interesting(char *filename) {
  uint16_t type;
  FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (!f) {
    printf("Error opening file '%s'.\n", filename);
    return 0;
  }

  fread(&type, sizeof(uint16_t), 1, f);
  fclose(f);

  switch (type) {
    case 0xD8FF:      // jpg
    case 0x5089:      // png
    case 0x4D42:      // bmp
    case 0x4952:      // webp
    case 0x4947:      // gif
    case 0x3F3C:      // possible svg.
    case 0x0000:      // possible mp4.
    case 0x5025:      // pdf.
      return 1;
    default:          // not interesting.
      return 0;
  }
}

/*Gets the configuration from a INI file*/
int get_config(
    char *browser, int *min_filesize, char *cache_dir, char *dest) {
  const char ini_file[] = "config.ini";
  char filesize_conf[100];
  long entry_length;

  entry_length = ini_gets("settings", "image_size_bytes", DEFAULT_FILE_SIZE,
      filesize_conf, sizearray(filesize_conf), ini_file);
  *min_filesize = atoi(filesize_conf);

  if (strcmp(browser, "firefox") == 0)
    entry_length = ini_gets("settings", "firefox_cache",
        DEFAULT_FIREFOX_CACHE, cache_dir, 255, ini_file);
  else if (strcmp(browser, "chromium") == 0)
    entry_length = ini_gets("settings", "chromium_cache",
        DEFAULT_CHROMIUM_CACHE, cache_dir, 255, ini_file);
  else {
    fprintf(stderr,
        "There is no configuration for %s browser.\n", browser);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  entry_length = ini_gets("settings", "destination_dir", DEFAULT_DEST_DIR,
      dest, 255, ini_file);

  if (entry_length <= 0)
    return 0;

  return 1;
}
```

And there is the problem, no matters if i pass the *'cache'* variable
or if i harcoded a string here, opendir failed and error is:
      **No such file or directory**

```
  dir = opendir(cache);
```

The code for read *".ini"* files is from https://www.compuphase.com/minini.htm, im a little newbee in this but i learn quickly, so please give me a hand with that.

Comment: c library doesn't evaluate environment variables and `~` in `"~/.cache/chromium/Default/Cache/"`

Comment: I'd replace `~` by the result of `getenv("HOME")` if that exists.

Comment: A small (unrelated) note: A macro like `sizearray` is dangerous to use. What if you forget to use it with an actual array, and use it with a pointer? For example, when passing arrays to functions they usually decays to pointers.

Comment: You use `fstat(input, &fileinfo);` in `OSCopyFile()`, why not use `stat` in `filesize()` instead of `fopen, fseek, ftell, ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when i use opendir with i.e opendir(argv[1]) there is no problem

That's because `argv[1]` contains the *expanded* version of `~/.cache/...` thanks to evaluation by the calling shell *before* the executable is started.

But passing a path like `~/.cache/...` to `opendir` doesn't work: C library does not evaluate `~` to user directory or environment variables.

You could make it compatible by testing for `~` explicitly and replacing by `getenv("HOME")`, something like this quite unsafe (but working) code:

```
const char *s = "~/.cache/.something";
...
char aux[1024];
if (s[0]=='~')
{
   sprintf(aux,"%s%s",getenv("HOME"),s+1);
   s = aux;
}
```

now if `s` starts by `~` if will be evaluated and replaced by (will point to) `aux`.

if the variable must be returned to a caller, better use `malloc` to allocate the string even if no substitution is to be made (and `free` it later). That's not the point, but proper string handling in C is always tricky.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, what silly mistake from me, good advice to check for ~ and replace with $HOME, and thanks for the warning with sizearray macro I'll keep it in mind, very, very, grateful man, thats solve the problem.